# When we divide P(x) with (x-1) the remainder is 2, when we divide it with (x-2) it is 5. We divide it with (x-1)(x-2) the remainder is ax+b.

Tags: polynomials

Find a and b.
ACCORDING TO ME since the remainder is ax+b it seems that the polynomial has no x^1. I've tried to express it with using a, b, c, d, e but there were many variable to solve it. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
$$P(x)=Q_1(x)(x-1)+2$$
so
$$P(1)=2$$

Also,
$$P(x)=Q_2(x)(x-2)+5$$
and therefore,
$$P(2)=5$$

Finally write
$$P(x)=Q_3(x)(x-1)(x-2)+ax+b$$

Substitute $x=1$ and $x=2$ to get
$$2=a+b$$
and
$$5=2a+b$$
and solve for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
p(x) = G(x)(x-1)(x-2) +ax+b
$$
$$
p(1) = a+b = 2 \\
p(2) = 2a+b = 5
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x) = (x-1) Q_1(x) + 2$. What happens if you further find the remainder of $Q_1(x)$ divided by $(x-2)$?

$$5 = P(2) = (2-1)Q_1(2) + 2\\
Q_1(2) = 3$$

Hence $Q_1(2)$ can be written as $(x-2)Q_2(x) + 3$. Back to $P(x)$,

$$\begin{align*}P(x) &= (x-1)\left[(x-2)Q_2(x)+3\right]+2\\
&= (x-1)(x-2)Q_2(x)+3(x-1)+2
\end{align*}$$